# How to make Page Up/Down buttons move less lines in AHK v2?

Tags: keyboard, autohotkey

So I've just found out about autohotkey maybe like a week ago. At the time I only used it to create a few shortcuts. Now I have been a bit confused. So when I press the Page Up/Down buttons, they move/scroll a lot and I've gotten confused on how to diminish the lines it scrolls through in autohotkey version 2.

I had found that someone had done it with authotkey version 1, which looked like this:
`PgUp::Send {Up 15}`.

I tried turning into this, which jus ends up typing out the line Up 15:

```
PgUp::
{
Send "Up 15"
return
}
```

I tried changing Up to WheelUp, Send to SendInput but those didn't work either. It's possible I'm missing something very obvious that I've failed to notice or figure out yet.

Comment: See [Repeating or Holding Down a Key](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/lib/Send.htm#Repeating_or_Holding_Down_a_Key)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at the link [Repeating or Holding Down a Key](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/lib/Send.htm#Repeating_or_Holding_Down_a_Key) given by @user3419297 in the comments. It now moves less lines and feels a lot smoother compared to before.

This is how I wrote it:

```
PgUp::
{
Loop 9
{
    Send "{Up down}" 
    Sleep 15 
}
Send "{Up up}"  ;Release the key.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not a big difference in the AHK v2 syntax for this.

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/howto/SendKeys.htm

And see the comment link.

So, putting it together:

```
PgUp::Send {Up 15}
```

should work.

If you had other things to do,

```
PgUp::
{
Send {Up 15}
; something else
}
```

Hth

Comment: both these examples give me "Error: Missing "propertyname:" in object literal."